Index, Match, Counta formula for excel
Worksheet design:

Data validation list:

I created an automated duty roster for my work. It is a duty circle from top to bottom. daily basis, emp 1 to emp last.
The table columns are:
B= serial no, C= Badge no, D= Name, E= Leave staring date, F= Ending date, G= Leave Status, H= Weekly Holiday (all employee 6 days work and one rest),I to AM = days of months (1 - 31)
also
Cells I6:AM6 are data validation list for starting duty each days
Cells I7:AM7 are days ( Sun, Mon,... etc)
Cells I8:AM8 are dates ( 1,2,3,..... etc)
I already created working formulas for the first three employees:
(=IF(OR(I$6="", I$8=""), "", IF(AND(I$8>=$E10, I$8<=$F10), $G10, IF(AND($H10=I$7, $H10<>""), "Off",          IF($I9="", I$6,INDEX(Duty, IF(MATCH(I$9, Duty, 0) + 1 > COUNTA(Duty), 1, MATCH(I$9, Duty, 0) + 1))))))

=IF(OR(I$6="", I$8=""), "", IF(AND(I$8>=$E11, I$8<=$F11), $G11, IF(AND($H11=I$7, $H11<>""), "Off",          IF(I$10="L",IF($I$6="", INDEX(Duty, IF(MATCH(I10, Duty, 0) + 1 > COUNTA(Duty), 1, MATCH(I10, Duty, 0) + 1)), $I$6), IF(I10="Off", IF($I$6="",INDEX(Duty, IF(MATCH(I10, Duty, 0) + 1 > COUNTA(Duty), 1, MATCH(I10, Duty, 0) + 1)), $I$6), INDEX(Duty, IF(MATCH(I10, Duty, 0) + 1 > COUNTA(Duty), 1, MATCH(I10, Duty, 0) + 1)))))))

=IF(OR(I$6="", I$8=""), "",IF(AND(I$8>=$E12, I$8<=$F12), $G12, IF(AND($H12=I$7, $H12<>""), "Off", IF(OR(I$10="L", I$10="Off"), IF(OR(I$11="L", I$11="Off"), INDEX(Duty, 1), INDEX(Duty, IF(MATCH(I$11, Duty, 0) + 1 > COUNTA(Duty), 1, MATCH(I$11, Duty, 0) + 1))), IF(OR(I$11="L", I$11="Off"),                INDEX(Duty, IF(MATCH(I$10, Duty, 0) + 1 > COUNTA(Duty), 1, MATCH(I$10, Duty, 0) + 1)), INDEX(Duty, IF(MATCH(I$11, Duty, 0) + 1 > COUNTA(Duty), 1, MATCH(I$11, Duty, 0) + 1)))))))

Now I need to create formula for next row. The above employees should be happen various things. it mean Leave (L), Duty off (Off).
If first day 1st employee may be L, second employee duty, third employee off then fourth employee should be duty (duty circle )
second day 1st employee duty, second employee off, third emp leave., etc.
Anyone have any idea of this formula or any suggestions?

So basically what you want to do is alternate between leave days (L), duty off (Off), and duty in. That's going to require dynamic states and changing states for each employee.
What we need:

Leave Days (L): Employees may be on leave based on the date range specified in their columns.
Off Days (Off): Employees will have an "Off" day if it matches their weekly time off
Duty: For the other days, employees should be on duty, and the formula should handle the rotation.

Acceptance Criteria:

Account for multiple employees on leave, duty, or off.
Example Monady: Employee 1 is on leave (L), Employee 2 is on duty, Employee 3 is off.
Check if employee is within the leave period (this is accomplished by checking leave),
Check if it's part of weekend,

Here’s a formula structure that you can use for the 4th employee (you can adapt it for subsequent rows by modifying the employee in question with their reference):
=IF(OR(I$6="", I$8=""), "", 
    IF(AND(I$8>=$E14, I$8<=$F14), $G14,  // Check if within leave dates
    IF(AND($H14=I$7, $H14<>""), "Off",  // Check if it's a weekly off time
    IF(MOD(ROW(), 3) = 1, "L",   // Leave (every 3 rows)
    IF(MOD(ROW(), 3) = 2, "Off",   // Off (every 3 rows)
    "Duty"   // Default
    )))))

Explanation:

The formula checks whether the date (I$8) is within the employee's leave period (E14 to F14).
If yes, it returns the leave status ($G14).
Weekly Holiday Check: If the employee's weekly holiday matches the day (I$7), it will return "Off".
MOD(ROW(), 3) ensures the rotation assigns the correctt label indicating type of time off.
Defaults to "Duty" on a day that they're supposed to be at work.
ROW() function ensures the pattern alternates every 3 rows across employees.

=IF(OR(I$6="", I$8=""), "", 
    IF(AND(I$8>=$E14, I$8<=$F14), $G14, 
    IF(AND($H14=I$7, $H14<>""), "Off", 
    IF(MOD(ROW(), 3) = 1, "L", 
    IF(MOD(ROW(), 3) = 2, "Off", 
    "Duty")))))


Thanks for your answer, I apply your formula for my worksheet. The result weekdays mark as "Off". Its ok. but other days 1-31 get result as "L". Example if i selected in 1/1/2025 emp1 ="L", emp2="Off", emp3=ECP1 (I select it from drop down list and who is the suitable emp for 1st duty) now emp4 should be = ECP2 ( drop down list's second duty). Just want if I select ($I6) duty from drop down list, the first emp must be list starting duty and others (without L and Off) need to duty circulate. (rotation).
